Computing Riemann-Roch space for genus 1 curve

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over an algebraically closed field $k$ of genus 1 and let $P_\infty\in X$. Compute $\mathcal{L}(nP_\infty)$ for $n\le 6$.

This is a past exam question for a first course in algebraic geometry. I don't know what a scheme is. Presumably, $P_\infty$ is a point at infinity with respect to some embedding.
By Riemann Roch, I can show $\ell(nP_\infty)=n$ for $n>0$. However, I have no idea what $\mathcal{L}(nP_\infty)$ looks like without having an equation in front of me (except $\mathcal{L}(P_\infty)=k$). I have looked at this question and its all based on very concrete examples.
Is it possible to "compute" this space? I'd like to know what someone who is a more experience at algebraic geometry than me thinks this question was expecting.

I would agree that if you want an explicit basis for the vector space, you'll need to have a concrete curve to work with. On the other hand, don't you know that every smooth curve of genus $1$ embeds in $\Bbb P^2$ as a smooth cubic $y^2=x^3+ax+b$?

@TedShifrin Funnily enough, that is the next question on the exam.

Oh, I see ... They're wanting a proof of that from Riemann-Roch. I believe the first question wanted the dimension, not an explicit basis. But who am I to guess ... ?

@TedShifrin Is $n\le 6$ relevant at all? I saw it mentioned in another post, which made me think.

There's certainly some stuff you can do here. One key fact we'll use is that $\mathcal{L}(nP)\subset\mathcal{L}((n+1)P)$:

$n=0$: this is just the constants, spanned by $1$.
$n=1$: $l(P)=1$, so this is again just the constants, spanned by $1$.
$n=2$: $l(2P)=2$, so this has a basis consisting of $1$ and some other function which we'll call $x$, which has a pole of order exactly 2 at $P$.
$n=3$: $l(3P)=3$, so this has a basis consisting of $1,x$, and some third function we'll call $y$, which has a pole of order exactly 3 at $P$.
$n=4$: $l(4P)=4$, and $x^2$ is a function with a pole of order exactly $4$ at $P$, so this has a basis consisting of $1,x,y,x^2$.
$n=5$: $l(5P)=5$, and $xy$ is a function with a pole of order exactly $5$ at $P$, so this has a basis consisting of $1,x,y,x^2,xy$.
$n=6$: $l(6P)=6$, and $x^3$ and $y^2$ are both functions with poles of order exactly $6$ at $P$, so this has a basis consisting of $1,x,y,x^2,xy,x^3$ or $1,x,y,x^2,xy,y^2$.

In any case, we have 7 vectors $1,x,y,x^2,xy,x^3,y^2$ in a $6$-dimensional vector space $\mathcal{L}(6P)$, so there is a linear dependence relation among them, and since $x^3$ and $y^2$ both have poles of order exactly $6$ at $P$, their coefficients must match, so after scaling, we have that the image of our curve satisfies an equation of the form $y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$ for $a_i\in k$ (this is commonly known as a long Weierstrass equation).
